# Displaying tab navigation bar without action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

Is it possible to show tab navigation bar in FragmentActivity using ViewPager, without showing navigation bar? Code I am using is from template in eclipse if you need that I will put it here.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar is the bar at the bottom of the screen that contains the HOME and BACK buttons, for devices that do not have off-screen capacitive buttons for those operations. The navigation bar has nothing to do with tabs or a `ViewPager`.

To display a `ViewPager` with tabs, but without using soon-to-be-deprecated action bar tabs, [use `PagerTabStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) or any number of third-party tabbed `ViewPager` indicators, such as [the `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator project](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) or [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).